# What Happened to Whitaker's Words?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, resource-request, spoken-language

Don't worry it still exists.

My problem is that I like speaking Latin, and Whitaker's Words has been my go-to for English to Latin translation. In the last couple of months, they have removed their English-to-Latin from their website.

Maybe it's just me, but I've looked around their website and cannot find the English-to-Latin section to save my life.

http://archives.nd.edu/words.html

Does anyone know where it went?

Comment: Now there's a blast from the past! I remember it as a program that ran with the MS-DOS-style command-line interface.

Comment: I don't know where it went, but here is a digitized version of Smith & Hall's English to Latin dictionary, which is more reliable than Whiticar's for English–Latin: https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/

Comment: I say good riddance - Whitaker's words was one of the most egregious examples of context-free gloss-translation, whose result, especially in the case of Latin, is constant misinterpretation of both the English and the Latin, and I'm certain this website is responsible for a good deal of bad Latin out there. It was conceived as a translation bank for **automatic machine translation,** and every time a learner mentions it, I feel it's imperative to warn against its use unless one is already experienced and can avoid its pitfalls. Smith & Hall is an example of how this should be done properly.

Answer (score 1):

Whitakers words is still available, there is an online version at:
https://latin-words.com/

There is a Android version for phones at Google play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ids1024.whitakerswords&hl=en_US&gl=US

There is an Apple version at:
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/william-whitakers-words/id1326344586

Hope that helps,
Vale.

Comment: The latin-words.com site doesn't seem to do English-to-Latin lookup, which Whitaker's Words notably did.

Comment: Wow, that is unfortunate. On the usual version a ~E switches mode to ENGLISH_TO_LATIN, apparently the people at latin-words.com did not do that.  I use a full command line version.  I also have the app on my Android phone, and that does support both modes.

Comment: Is the command line version still available anywhere? The site I once got it at seems to be gone.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu linux, the last time I got Whitakers words I downloaded the source

Comment: I am running Ubuntu linux, the last time I got Whitakers words I downloaded the source code and built it myself.  I am running Version 1.97FC, (1993-2006 copyright). The website that I downloaded from does not seem to exist anymore.  Closest thing I found today was on github.com, the link is https://github.com/mk270/whitakers-words. The source code is there and there are instructions for building the software executable for Linux.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you still need a good source for English to Latin translation, I have started building my own version of Whitakers Words, that has that feature.

https://learninglatin.net/translate

Answer (score 1):

Whitaker's Words English to Latin dictionary is available at [latinlens.org](https://latinlens.org).